# C# Persistent Value - Console App Scheduled Task

Tags: c#, scheduled-tasks, console-application

I have a console app written in C# that will be run as a scheduled task.

I'm wondering what would be the best way to create a unique, persistent value that can be used throughout the app each time it runs.  I want to use this value as an unique id for the task run for logging purposes.  If this was a web app, which I am most familiar with, I'd use a session variable or a cache.  Not sure what would be best to use on a console.

TIA

Comment: Does this value change on every execution? or identical for every execution?

Comment: Would a GUID work?

Comment: changes with each execution

Comment: guid would work

Comment: Could also use a unique timestamp that could give some contextual information...i.e. DateTimeOffset.Now.ToString("o")

Comment: I was thinking something like this in the Program class:

public static string TaskId { get { return Guid.NewGuid().ToString(); } }